# Python - Saving an image from a url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

Is there a way to save a picture from a url using urllib or Beautiful Soup?

-Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply write to a file while reading the data.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

local_file_name = 'localfile.txt'
remote_url = 'http://localhost/example'

remote_file = urlopen(remote_url)
local_file = open(file_name, "w")
local_file.write(remote_file.read())
local_file.close()
```

Comment: Kind of a lukewarm example, although you don't come across many multi-gigabyte images.

Answer (score 5):

You want [`urllib.urlretrieve()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve).

Answer (score 3):

no need of Beautiful Soup as i assume you need to read a binary file.
Just read the stream and store it as a file.

```
import urllib                                       
url = "http://example.com/file.pdf"
uopen = urllib.urlopen(url)
stream = uopen.read()
file = open('filename','w')
file.write(stream)
file.close()
```

btw. to address the issue of multigigabit images

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('url', 'filename')
```

2nd code snippet gonna be more reliable.. thanks to `Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams` enlighten this issue of large files.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote this for myself.

```
def get_file(url):
    file_temp = NamedTemporaryFile()
    file_temp.write(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    file_temp.flush()
    return File(file_temp)
```